# Навигационный бар загораживает заголовки

Tags: html, css

Верстаю резюме сайт, и столкнулся с проблемой, что навигационный бар загораживает заголовок, тоесть выглядит вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а мне надо, чтобы выглядело так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался делать отступы, но навигационный бар следует за этим заголовком и постоянно загораживает его, какой бы отступ я не делал, как это можно исправить? Я добавил сюда код, я убрал много кода, оставил только две секции, чтобы показать, но дело в том, что тут не так работает как у меня, точнее в малом виде работает как у меня, но если развернуть на всю страницу, то тут навбар не загораживает заголовок, но чутка налезает, но может все равно получится показать по этому примеру, как сделать отступы, чтобы ничего не налезало. Также как можно сделать без js или jquery, только с помощью css плавные переходы между страницами, тоесть когда я нажимаю в навбаре на about, у меня там плавно переходило, а не как сейчас?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
  }

.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #212121;
    z-index: 2;
} 

h1 {
    margin: 50px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    float: left;
    font-family: cursive;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E55D87 0%, #5FC3E4  51%, #E55D87  100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.navbar {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    
}

li { 
    display:inline-block; 
    margin:0;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

li:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px solid aqua;  
    transform: scaleX(0);  
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

li:hover::after { 
    transform: scaleX(1); 
}

.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E55D87 0%, #5FC3E4  51%, #E55D87  100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-family: cursive;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-size: 200% auto;
}

.button:hover {
    background-position: right center;
}

.my-photo {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-left: 700px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

 .h2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background: #19CFB1;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #19CFB1 0%, #C978CF 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
}
  
#text {
    background: #1338CF;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #1338CF 0%, #CF70AF 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    line-height: 50px; 
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
}

.home-image {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;    
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -1; 
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    background-image: url("./img/foto-mustang-6-shelby-gt500_01.jpg")   
}

.home-image::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

blockquote {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 60px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
 
blockquote:before {
    content: "\201C";
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #CBDDE7;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 362px;
    top: 596px;
    z-index: -1;
}

blockquote p {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 130px;  
}

.about {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#about{
    width: 1300px;
    height: 687px;
    padding: 0 80px;
    margin: auto;
}

.title {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: cursive;
    z-index: -1;
}

.title::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 180px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #111;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.title::after {
    content: "who i am";
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: crimson;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: #fff;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.image {
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.column-right {
    width: 55%;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>CV</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#home" class="button">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" class="button">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio" class="button">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="button">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1>My CV</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="home" id="home">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="home-header home-header-small">
            <div class="home-image"></div>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="content-center">
                <div class="profile-image">
                <img src="" class="my-photo"/>
                </div>
                <div class="h2">Lorem ipsum</div>
                <p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <blockquote>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <footer>— <cite>Lorem ipsum</cite></footer>
            </blockquote>  
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section class="about" id="about">      
            <h2 class="title">About me</h2>
            <div class="content">
                    <img src="" class="image"/>
                <div class="column-right">
                    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum</div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit minus impedit maxime, quae soluta quis cumque perferendis! Doloribus quaerat, placeat iste facere, aspernatur ex cum veritatis laudantium, officia, non porro exercitationem incidunt quis dolore? Officia ex accusamus expedita optio, voluptatem minus? In maiores omnis aperiam earum ab molestiae beatae laborum blanditiis incidunt, delectus dolor, id voluptates optio aspernatur aliquam saepe atque labore?</p>
                </div>
            </div>    
    </section>
```

Comment: Сделайте для `body` `padding-top` равный высоте `.navbar`. А ещё почитайте про HTML и CSS, чтобы знать что для чего используется (`z-index: -1`, `footer` используется для другого, отсутствие адаптивности (всё свёрстано на пикселях)).

Comment: @De.Minov  Да, я знаю для чего используется z-index, для наложение, чтобы фоновый элемент, не налазил на передний, он используется, только в position: absolute, relative. Я поставил body padding-top равный высоте .navbar, но там вышло это https://prnt.sc/YOeH15WtAMlk

Comment: De.Minov А что, Вы, имели ввиду про footer? Тут у меня его нет, он у меня в самом конце.

Comment: прижмите `.header` к верху экрана через `top: 0;`. Насчёт `footer`, он у вас зачем-то находится внутри `blockquote`.

Comment: @De.Minov, К сожалению не работает, я пробывал и другое там, но тоже не работает, может у меня там какие-то стили что-то блокирует или может очень поломано у меня все). Кстати, хотел уточнить, чтобы у меня блоки не разлетались по углам, при масштабировании, лучше применять vh или vw вместо пикселей, да?

Comment: Возможно, надо бы глянуть на живой пример. Чтобы не гадать какие стили что нарушают существует девтул. Лучше почитать про виды вёрстки, понять что и где используется.